# Сломался старый скрипт поиска видео на youtube по запросу

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, youtube

Был у меня такой [скрипт для поиска на ютубе](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ac4dd75dbc5322cc3979e5439e82a0932cf05041/telegram_bot_examples/speak_pict_youtube.py#L77) (использовал в телеграм боте):

```
import urllib
import re
import random

link = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": msg})
content = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?" + link)
search_results = re.findall('href=\"\/watch\?v=(.*?)\"', content.read().decode())
if len(search_results) > 0:
    search_results = search_results[0:9:1]
    choice_f = random.choice(search_results)
    yt_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+choice_f
```

Он был не аккуратный, работал через регулярки, и вообще, был не моим :)

А сейчас он ничего не возвращает и хотелось бы разобраться что поменялось и как починить его.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Если коротко (*хочется подробнее, посмотри ниже*), то раньше скрипт работал потому-что результат поиска возвращался в ответе на запрос, в HTML.

Сейчас же результат поиска будет внутри [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), его нужно извлечь и обработать.

[Готовое решение (upd 28.10.2020, поддержка `var ytInitialData`):](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/94d32f803ff2fa58f3fa4309a62d53b01c55c0f1/html_parsing/youtube_com__results_search_query.py)

```
import json
from typing import List, Tuple, Optional
import re

# pip install dpath
import dpath.util

import requests


USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
PATTERNS = [
    re.compile(r'window\["ytInitialData"\] = (\{.+?\});'),
    re.compile(r'var ytInitialData = (\{.+?\});'),
]

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT


def get_ytInitialData(url: str) -> Optional[dict]:
    rs = session.get(url)

    for pattern in PATTERNS:
        m = pattern.search(rs.text)
        if m:
            data_str = m.group(1)
            return json.loads(data_str)


def search_youtube(text_or_url: str) -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
    if text_or_url.startswith('http'):
        url = text_or_url
    else:
        text = text_or_url
        url = f'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={text}'

    items = []

    data = get_ytInitialData(url)
    if not data:
        return items

    videos = dpath.util.values(data, '**/videoRenderer')
    if not videos:
        videos = dpath.util.values(data, '**/playlistVideoRenderer')

    for video in videos:
        if 'videoId' not in video:
            continue

        url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video['videoId']
        try:
            title = dpath.util.get(video, 'title/runs/0/text')
        except KeyError:
            title = dpath.util.get(video, 'title/simpleText')

        items.append((url, title))

    return items
```

---

## Теперь подробнее

Давайте попробуем разобраться с парсингом с самого начала. Внизу будет **много** скриншотов!

### Для начала изучаем механизм поиска:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, для поиска нужно оформить URL в таким виде:

> `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=`**{text}**

Тут ничего не поменялось.

#### Изучаем структуру через инспектор браузера

Тыкаем на правую кнопку мышки и выбираем **Inspect Element**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откроется панель такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Изучаем и ищем ссылку на видео:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Попробуем попарсить:

Например, поищем теги видео, например `ytd-video-renderer`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slipknot')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
print(len(root.select('ytd-video-renderer')))
# 0
```

Ничего...

А если поискать ссылку, увиденную в инспекторе?

```
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slipknot')
print(rs.text.count('/watch?v=5abamRO41fE'))
# 4
```

Интересно... Получается ссылка есть, но она не в том теге.

#### Посмотрим, что приходит в ответ при запросе поиска:

- Можно через браузер, через правой кнопкой на мышки и выбрать **View Page Source**
- Или скриптом:

  ```
  import requests
  rs = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slipknot')
  with open('rs.html', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(rs.content)
  ```

Тег `ytd-video-renderer` не найден...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашли `ytd-video-renderer`, но это в [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А что насчет ссылки? Тоже в [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (у меня сломался поиск в Page Source, поэтому показываю в Notepad++):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Получается, данные с поиском находятся в объекте, находящимся в `window["ytInitialData"]`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### `Изучим window["ytInitialData"]`

Как видим из структуры, видео находятся в объектах **videoRenderer**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Теперь попробуем вытащить значение из `window["ytInitialData"]` и обработать его.

Для вытаскивания используем [регулярное выражение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), а для парсинга [модуль json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Как видим, данные успешно вытаскиваются, парсятся и обрабатываются:

```
import json
import re
import requests
PATTERN = re.compile(r'window\["ytInitialData"\] = (\{.+?\});')

rs = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slipknot')

m = re.search(r'window\["ytInitialData"\] = (\{.+?\});', rs.text)
data_str = m.group(1)
print(data_str)
# {"responseContext":{"serviceTrackingParams":[{"service":"GUIDED_HELP","params":[{"key":"context","va ...

data = json.loads(data_str)
print(data['contents']['twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer']['primaryContents']['sectionListRenderer']['contents'][0]['itemSectionRenderer']['contents'][2]['videoRenderer'])
# {'videoId': '5abamRO41fE', 'thumbnail': {'thumbnails': [{'url': ...
```

Для удобства работы с словарем, я воспользуюсь модулем [dpath.util](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/), например так можно вытащить значения всех объектов с ключом **videoRenderer**:

```
import dpath.util

...

result = dpath.util.values(data, '**/videoRenderer')
print(len(result))
# 39
```

#### Это все. Надеюсь, это было полезно