# Парсер youtube подправить код

Tags: python

Парсер прекрасно раньше работал.
Сейчас стал выдавать исключение:

```
>>> Python 3.8.0a1 (tags/v3.8.0a1:e75eeb00b5, Feb  3 2019, 19:46:54) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Парсер youtube\parsery_youtube.py", line 9
    match = re.findall('(\?v\=(.+?)\")+.*(title="(.+?)\")', doc)
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \?
```

---

Вот код самого парсера:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re, os, sys
def findyoutube(x):
    mas=[]
    sq='http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+urllib.parse.quote(x)
    doc = urllib.request.urlopen(sq).read().decode('utf8',errors='ignore')
    match = re.findall('(\?v\=(.+?)\")+.*(title="(.+?)\")', doc)
    if not(match is None):
        for ii in match:
            if(len(ii)<25):
                mas.append(ii[3] + '\n*replace*' + ii[1] + '\n')
    mas=dict(zip(mas,mas)).values()
    mas2=[]
    for y in mas: mas2.append(f'{y}'.replace('*replace*', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='))
    return mas2
print(findyoutube('болонская+удочка°'))
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as output:
    for i in findyoutube('болонская+удочка'):
        output.write(i+'\n')
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163422

Comment: Если по ошибке смотреть, то нужно `\?` заменить на `\\?`. И вообще лучше r-строки для регулярок использовать.

Comment: Заменил в 9 строке: \? заменить на \\? Опять выдало ошибку: >>> 
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Парсер youtube\parsery_youtube.py", line 9
    match = re.findall('(\\?v\=(.+?)\")+.*(title="(.+?)\")', doc)
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \=
>>>