# Как получить или спарсить идентификатор видео Youtube?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - пользователь вводит текст боту, и этот текст передается в запрос на поиск видео в `Youtube`; но перед тем как писать логику бота - я решил перепроверить и сделать ее в отдельном файле. Хочу отметить, что требуется это сделать без `selenium` и `Youtube API` !

Я отправляю запрос методом `GET` и хочу получить идентификатор `/watch?=значение`, но никаким способом парсинга мне не удается получить это значение, так как данный идентификатор загружается в динамическом скрипте. Если вывести `html` с помощью `r.text`, то поиском в консоли можно обнаружить данный идентификатор в тэге `<scrtipt>...</script>`(в моем случае интересует `href="/watch?v=o_l4Ab5FRwM`. Данные из этого тэга, можно сказать, являются преогромнейшим словарем, и разобраться в нем крайне трудно.

Также я понимаю, что `bs4` не работает со скриптами, но я хочу получить значение из этого тэга:

`a id="thumbnail" class="yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" rel="null" href="/watch?v=o_l4Ab5FRwM">`

Если проверить в консоли - в дереве `HTML` не обнаружить ни этот `class` ни этот `id`. Приведу небольшой пример кода:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=five+finger+death+punch')
print(r.text)

# Написал только для примера, что эти варианты не подходят!  
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#sel = '#thumbnail'
#soup.select(sel).get('href')
#soup.find('a', class_='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail')
```

Как мне получить данный идентификатор видео? Я так полагаю, что можно сделать это регулярным выражением, но я пока что слаб в этой теме, поэтому хочу увидеть более альтернативные варианты, но можно было бы и получить пример `re`. Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1163422/201445

Comment: @gil9red, приятно, что так все подробно описано:) Это то что мне нужно. Это то, что я пытался решить ближайшие 2-3 часа. Благодарю)

Comment: @gil9red, появилась небольшая проблемка. Я пытался запустить ваш тестовый код, но почему-то `items` всегда оказывается пустым (запускал ваши примеры под `if main`).

Comment: Похоже, что-то поменялось в отдаваемых результатах, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Причина в том, что для того запроса данные хранились не в `window["ytInitialData"]`, а в `var ytInitialData`. Обновил код в том ответе